# How can we see the MIP log when calling AMPL from Matlab and using Gurobi as solver?

Tags: matlab, gurobi, ampl

Does anyone know how can I print the MIP logging on Matlab when calling AMPL from it? I'm using Gurobi as solver.

My Matlab code do:

```
system(['ampl.exe ' modelName.run]);
```

The `modelName.run` file has the AMPL code and calls Gurobi:

```
model model.md;
data input.dat;
option solver gurobi;
problem oampl: fo, constraints;
solve oampl;
```

The `model.md` has the objective function (fo) and the constraints.

I would like to see the log progress (initial solution, nodes, iterations, bounds etc.) of the MILP resolution process on Matlab. Should I do some parameter setting on Matlab or on AMPL? Or it can't be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using Gurobi via AMPL the logging is turned off by default, you can turn it on with the following option:

```
option gurobi_options 'outlev 1' ;
```

More Details about the AMPL-Gurobi options can be found here:
http://www.gurobi.com/documentation/7.0/ampl-gurobi/parameters.html

Comment: Great! Thank you!